# How did David Dickey (bassist in the band America) inadvertently fly home to America?

Tags: history, pop, live-music

I just read on wikipedia that America bassist David Dickey (who died in 2016) missed a European tour because after landing there, he inadvertently flew back to America. There has to be a story here — how does one (or in this case, Dickey specifically) inadvertently fly across the ocean?

BTW, he is one of my favorite bassists, especially for his work on "Sister Golden Hair"

Answer (score -1):

He didn’t. He flew home on purpose for personal reasons

Comment: any links to explain that, for example press article afterwards etc ?